# How to limit the number of nodes? (Spritekit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a little problem. check it out:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {

var Location:CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
var Node:SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(Location)

 if(Location.x < self.size.width/2) {

        node2.addchild(sprite2)
        node1.removeFromParent()
}
if (Location.x > self.size.width/2) {

        node1.addchild(sprite1)

        node2.removeFromParent()
}
```

The problem is that when I tap for exmple 10 times on the same side of the screen (let's say, the right side) it apppears 10 spritenodes and I can't use "hidden" because of the physicsBody. Can you guys help me?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: when I tap on the left side the hero is in the left side the right hero disappear, but when I tap 2 times on the left it creates two heroes..please tell me that you understood Im not that goood in english.

Comment: You need to track the left/right sprites with a property - if it isn't nil then take an appropriate action - either move the existing sprite to the new location or remove the existing sprite and create a new one.  You don't say what the desired behaviour of a second tap should be